# Rails - with Pundit Scopes in policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit, scopes

I am trying to figure out how to use pundit policy scopes in my article policy.

I have written an article policy, that nests a scope and then has a resolve method in it. The resolve method has alternatives based on who the `current_user` is.

My article policy has:

```
class ArticlePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
    class Scope < Scope
        attr_reader :user, :scope

        # I now think I don't need these actions because I have changed the action in the articles controller to look for policy scope.
         # def index?
         #      article.state_machine.in_state?(:publish)
         # end

            def show?

            article.state_machine.in_state?(:publish) ||
            user == article.user ||
            article.state_machine.in_state?(:review) && user.org_approver ||
            false
        end
            end

            def create?
                article.user.has_role?(:author) 

            end

            def update?
                # user && user.article.exists?(article.id) #&& user.article.created_at < 15.minutes.ago
                user.present? && user == article.user 
                # add current state is not published or approved
            end

            def destroy?
                user.present? && user == article.user 
                # user.admin? 
                # user.present?
                # user && user.article.exists?(article.id)
            end



    end     

    private
        def article
            record
        end

        def resolve
            if user == article.user
                scope.where(user_id: user_id)
            elsif approval_required?
                scope.where(article.state_machine.in_state?(:review)).(user.has_role?(:org_approver))
            else
                article.state_machine.in_state?(:publish)    
            end 
        end


        def approval_required?

            true if article.user.has_role?(:author)
                 # elsif article.user.profile.organisation.onboarding.article_approval == true


            # if onboarding (currently in another branch) requires org approval
        end

        def org_approver
            if article.user.has_role? :author
                user.has_role? :editor
            # if onboarding (currently in another branch) requires org approval, then the approval manager for that org
            elsif article.user.has_role? :blogger
                user.has_role? :editor if user.profile.organisation.id == article.user.profile.organisation.id  
          end
        end

end
```

The example in the pundit docs shows how to use this for an index, but how do I use the resolve method for a show action? Can I write several resolve methods for the various other controller actions?

[Pundit Scopes](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#scopes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont have much experience with `pundit`, however by looking at documentation and your code the code I can see 2 things.

1 - You shouldnt use methods like `show?` inside your scope class.

inside your scope class, you should use only methods that returns a scope. the methods that returns boolean should be in the Policy level. But in your code I can boolean methods inside the scope class.

`Instances of this class respond to the method resolve, which should return some kind of result which can be iterated over. For ActiveRecord classes, this would usually be an ActiveRecord::Relation.`

[from the docs](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#scopes)

2 - Given that Scope are POROs (Plain Old Ruby Object) you can have more than one resolve methods (of course with a different name :)), because resolve is just a method name.

May be you can do something like

```
#policy
class ArticlePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :scope

  def initialize(user, scope)
    @user  = user
    @scope = scope
  end


  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      # some scope
    end

    def resolve_show
      #scope for show action 
      # E.g scope.all
    end
  end

  def show?
    article.state_machine.in_state?(:publish) ||
      user == article.user ||
      article.state_machine.in_state?(:review) && user.org_approver || false
  end
end
```

in your controller

```
#Articles controller
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    authorize Article 
    ArticlePolicy::Scope.new(current_user, Article).resolve_show
  end
  ...
end
```

This should first authorize your show method with `ArticlePolicy#show?` and the scope from `ArticlePolicy::Scope#resolve_show`

Disclaimer: Untested code, use at your own risk ;)

Comment: Thanks so much @sameera207. This got me started on solving the problems. For others - the scopes need to be separated from the action controls. The scopes can be nuanced for the specifics of the data set. The action controls need to be capable of a true or false outcome (and if true, the scope is then applied).